# Is there a way in CSS, JS, or JQuery to change all font sizes of an element by a specific factor (e.g. 1/2 of what the CSS says)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on a report where the worker goes through it on the `PHP` website and then prints it out once completed. That is all fairly simple; however, when it prints, I'm going to want the size to be smaller than on the 46" widescreen the worker uses so that the `table`s fit on each page cleanly...

My *normal* `CSS` looks like this:

```
div#reportPage {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

table#report {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

table#report>thead>tr>th,
table#report>tbody>tr>td {
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
}

table#report>thead>tr>th.pt {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}

th.dn::after {
    white-space: pre;
    content: "\A Alt Name";
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-style: italic;
}

th.prov>p {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

`PHP`/`HTML`

```
function weeklyTable($patient)
{
    include "system/connect.php";
    try {
        $regData = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `medications` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `patient` = '$patient' AND `type` = 1 ORDER BY `name` ASC")->fetchAll();
        echo "<table id='report'>";
        echo "<thead><tr><th colspan=99 class='pt'>$patient - Standard Meds</th></tr>
                     <tr><th class='dn'>Drug Name</th><th>Rx #</th><th class='prov'>Provider<p>Department</p></th><th>Dose/Pill</th>
                     <th>Q/F</th><th>TOD</th><th>Su</th><th>M</th><th>Tu</th><th>W</th><th>Th</th><th>F</th><th>Sa</th></tr></thead>";
        foreach ($regData as $rx) {
            if ($rx['type'] == 1) {
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";

        $regData = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `medications` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `patient` = '$patient' AND `type` = 2 ORDER BY `name` ASC")->fetchAll();
        echo "<table id='report'>";
        echo "<thead><tr><th colspan=99 class='pt'>$patient - Advanced Meds</th></tr>
                     <tr><th class='dn'>Drug Name</th><th>Rx #</th><th class='prov'>Provider<p>Department</p></th><th>Dose/Pill</th>
                     <th>Q/F</th><th>TOD</th><th>Su</th><th>M</th><th>Tu</th><th>W</th><th>Th</th><th>F</th><th>Sa</th></tr></thead>";
        foreach ($regData as $rx) {
            if ($rx['type'] == 1) {
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";

        $regData = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `medications` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `patient` = '$patient' AND `type` = 3 ORDER BY `name` ASC")->fetchAll();
        echo "<table id='report'>";
        echo "<thead><tr><th colspan=99 class='pt'>$patient - OTC Meds</th></tr>
                     <tr><th class='dn'>Drug Name</th><th>Rx #</th><th class='prov'>Provider<p>Department</p></th><th>Dose/Pill</th>
                     <th>Q/F</th><th>TOD</th><th>Su</th><th>M</th><th>Tu</th><th>W</th><th>Th</th><th>F</th><th>Sa</th></tr></thead>";
        foreach ($regData as $rx) {
            if ($rx['type'] == 1) {
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br/><br/>";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "PDOError: {$e->getMessage()}";
        die();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "ExceptionError: {$e->getMessage()}";
    }
}
```

I'm still working on the tables and such, so please don't worry if you see something stupid in there, I literally copied and pasted the first one multiple times.

So my 'normal' `font-size` is 1em (with a few exceptions)... If I want it to print at a 0.75 modifier (75% of the original font-size) on **ALL** items, including those that are at 1.25em and 0.8em - is there a clean way to do that besides re-coding the css (I'm already going to be doing `@media print`, so please don't think I've forgotten that)?

Also - no need to worry about injection - this is all input on our side, and validated/`prepared` there.

Comment: `body { font-size: 75%; }` works, unless you use absolute units on smaller portions of the page. I would give your body tag an id of body too, so that you can make simple powerful rules to cascade over your defaults, like `#body table { font-size: 66%; }`; the ID part of the selector makes it over-ride.

Comment: You might consider adopting LESS/SCSS stylesheets for that. https://lesscss.org/ for instance. Although it would require to refactor your css code

Comment: So, if I'm reading that correctly.. doing `body { font-size: 75% }` within the `@media print` would take what I had in the base `CSS` and adjust it down to 75% of the *hard-coded* data (like `#body>table>thead>tr>th { font-size: 2em }`), making the computed value `#body>table>thead>tr>th { font-size: 1.5em }` ..?

Comment: @GregoryMolchanov I may look into that next time - I appreciate the info.

Comment: @dandavis could you throw that in an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So my 'normal' font-size is 1em (with a few exceptions)... If I want it to print at a 0.75 modifier (75% of the original font-size) on ALL items, including those that are at 1.25em and 0.8em - is there a clean way to do that besides re-coding the css (I'm already going to be doing @media print, so please don't think I've forgotten that)

I'd suggest the cleanest approach is:

```
@media print {

  :root {
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  body,
  body * {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

`0.75rem` has an advantage in that it remains consistently *relative-to-document-root*, while both `0.75em` and `75%` are *relative-to-parent*.

---

### Further Reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#ems_and_rems